# Java App not loading on tomcat 9 centos 7

Tags: java, tomcat, centos7

I'm pretty new to linux and I've been thrown into it. So far I made it work a few times, but this time it got me bad. The aim is to cluster tomcat and load balance with nginx but the app error is taking too much time from me. The app is correctly deployed by tomcat but is not accesible through browser. I've checked permissions, dns resolution, ports. The app resides out of webapps folder.
Java 8 installed from yum
Tomcat 9 taken with wget
Configured tomcat service to autostart
Added execution permits to .sh's

I honestly dont know what I'm missing. The same app currently runs under centos 6 on production server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the firewall (iptables)? Sometimes that is the culprit. From the server itself, try doing a curl on the localhost url and see if you get a response.

Comment: What response are you getting when you try to connect using the browser?

Comment: I disabled firewalld service and selinux too as Im just testing. If I change the host to default in /tomcat/conf/server.xml it instantly loads. Tomcat shows no error, it deploys the app with no error. If I try to access the dns of the VM if does not shows anything.

Comment: I had a bad day about Tomcat on Centos 7.4 x64 today.
In one put. It didn't work. Tomcat listen 8080, accept the connections but never send a response.
I just downloaded tomcat 8.5.24 from the apache site and untar-ed it
I also installed succesfully oracle java.
Then I tried a server running Centos 6.9 x64. Repeated all the installation process and everything worked fine.

I didn't find any post about this issue on the web and I am not sure if this is an issue of Centos, Tomcat or Digitalocean's Centos 7.

If you find out something please post a comment.

Comment: I'm not glad to hear that but I feel less lonely now. I stopped my workday with a ready to test 6.9 centos and 8.5.24 tomcat. As soon as I can I'll do testing and comment any news here. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working. I was missing the `<Context.../>` just beneath my `<Host.../>` declaration. Production server doesn't have that line, so I supposed there was no need for it. Nevertheless the first time I got it working, I don't remeber having that set up.

Like this:

`</Realm>`

`<Host name="hostname" appBase="/app/base/" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">`

`<Context path="" docBase="/app/base/" reloadable="true"/>`

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />`

`</Host>`

`</Engine>`

`</Service>`

`</Server>`